# htaccess 301 redirect from old site to new site with rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my first question on this site, because usually with enough searching/hacking I can figure most things out. However I'm stuck and any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a typical 301 redirect in a .htaccess file on my old domain.

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/
```

This is working fine till a webpage from the old site gets directed to the new site that then has the following rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_([0-9]+).htm ../courses/course_view.php?item=$1&courseid=$2 [QSA,L]
```

When coming from the old site the url ends up looking like this...

```
http://newdomain.com/courses/A-J-Jolly_3385.htm?item=A-J-Jolly&courseid=3385
```

I can not figure out why it is adding the variables to the end of the url. When visiting the page directly from the new domain it looks correct.

```
http://newdomain.com/courses/A-J-Jolly_3385.htm
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!